# Sorting std::unordered_map by key

Tags: c++, sorting, unordered-map

How can I sort an `unordered_map` by key? I need to print an `unordered_map` sorted by key.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> unordered;

std::map<int, int> ordered(unordered.begin(), unordered.end());
for(auto it = ordered.begin(); it != ordered.end(); ++it)
     std::cout << it->second;
```

Comment: I have declared unorderedmap as `std::unordered_map<int, unsigned long>  *myunorderedmap;` But `std::map<int, unsigned long> ordered(myunorderedmap->begin, myunorderedmap->end);` gives error

Comment: begin and end are functions. Use `ordered(myunorderedmap->begin(), myunorderedmap->end())` instead of what you used and all will be fine.

Comment: And don't forget, if you don't care about retaining the elements in the initial container, `make_move_iterator` can be used to move the elements into the new container: `std::map<int, int> ordered(std::make_move_iterator(unordered.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(unordered.end()));`

Answer (score 31):

An alternate solution is to construct a vector of the keys, sort the vector, and print per that sorted vector. This will be considerably faster than the approaches that constructed a map from the ordered map, but will also involve more code.

```
std::unordered_map<KeyType, MapType> unordered;
std::vector<KeyType> keys;

keys.reserve (unordered.size());
for (auto& it : unordered) {
    keys.push_back(it.first);
}
std::sort (keys.begin(), keys.end());
for (auto& it : keys) {
    std::cout << unordered[it] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: It will be even faster if you use a vector and `std::sort` instead of a list.

Comment: And even marginally faster still if you reserve that vector with the required length (if you must use push_back)

Comment: @Steven Lu what could you use instead of `push_back` if you didn't care about the order, as in this example?

Answer (score 14):

Are you *sure* you need this? Because that is not possible. An `unordered_map` is a hash container, that is, the keys are **hashed**. Inside of the container, they don't have the same representation as on the outside. Even the name implies that you can't sort it. It's one of the criteria to choose a hash container: You do **not** need a specific order.

If you do, get a normal `map`. The keys are automatically sorted in a strict-weak ordering. If you need another sort, write your own comparator.

If you only need to print it sorted, the following may be inefficient, but it's as close as you'll get if you still want to keep the `unordered_map`.

```
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct map_streamer{
  std::ostream& _os;

  map_streamer(std::ostream& os) : _os(os) {}

  template<class K, class V>
  void operator()(std::pair<K,V> const& val){
    // .first is your key, .second is your value
    _os << val.first << " : " << val.second << "\n";
  }
};

template<class K, class V, class Comp>
void print_sorted(std::unordered_map<K,V> const& um, Comp pred){
  std::map<K,V> m(um.begin(), um.end(), pred);
  std::for_each(m.begin(),m.end(),map_streamer(std::cout));
}

template<class K, class V>
void print_sorted(std::unordered_map<K,V> const& um){
  print_sorted(um, std::less<int>());
}
```

[Example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/rUcAF).
Note that in C++0x, you can replace the two overloads with one function with a default template argument:

```
template<class K, class V, class Comp = std::less<int> >
void print_sorted(std::unordered_map<K,V> const& um, Comp pred = Comp()){
  std::map<K,V> m(um.begin(), um.end(), pred);
  std::for_each(m.begin(),m.end(),map_streamer(std::cout));
}
```

Comment: You could use `std::ostream_iterator` and `std::copy` instead of your own `streamer` thingie.

Comment: @Itjax: On a second thought, no, because `std::for_each` will give me a `std::pair<K,V>` and I'd need to split that anyways. My first implementation didn't work for that reason, `std::pair` can't be streamed.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to David's answer, we can use `std::set` to sort the key first:

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> unordered;
std::set<int> keys;
for (auto& it : unordered) keys.insert(it.first);
for (auto& it : keys) {
    std::cout << unordered[it] << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector to store your key value pairs, then sort them in vector, put them back at map at last.

```
#include <iostream>                                 
#include <unordered_map>                                 
#include <algorithm>                                 
#include <vector>                                 

using namespace std;                                

int main(){                                
    unordered_map<string, int> sdict = {{"hello", 11 }, {"world", 52}, {"tommy", 3}};               
    unordered_map<string, int> resdict;          

    vector<pair<string, int>> tmp;
    for (auto& i : sdict)                                         
        tmp.push_back(i);                                

    for (auto& i : sdict)       
        cout <<  i.first << " => " << i.second << endl;  

    // sort with descending order.
    sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(),                                   
    [&](pair<string, int>& a, pair<string, int>& b) { return a.second < b.second; });

    for (auto& i : tmp)                          
    {                           
        resdict[i.first] = i.second;                   
    }                                

    cout << "After sort." << endl;   
    for (auto& i : resdict)     
        cout <<  i.first << " => " << i.second << endl;           
    return 0;                                              

}
```

Compile with following commands.

```
g++ --std=c++11 test_sort_ordered_map.cpp
```

The result is:

```
tommy => 3
hello => 11
world => 52
After sort.
world => 52
hello => 11
tommy => 3
```