# Why STL unordered_map and unordered_set cannot be sorted by STL algorithms?

Tags: sorting, c++11, stl, unordered-map, unordered-set

I'll start by illustrating a simple use case example:

- Consider the problem of a social security ID database, where in C++ code is modelled as a `std::unordered_map` where its key is the social security ID of a person and its value is a `std::string` with the full-name of that person (e.g., `std::unordered_map<int, std::string> DB;`).
- Consider also, that there's a request for printing this database sorted in ascending order based on the person's ID (i.e., `std::unordered_map`'s key).
- Naively, one would think to use `std::sort` in order to sort the `std::unordered_map` according to the requested criteria and then print it, like the example code below:

---

```
   std::sort(DB.begin(), DB.end());
   for(auto p : DB) std::cout << "ID(" << p.first
                              << ") - " 
                              << p.second 
                              << std::endl;
```

---

- However, this is not the case, because use of `std::sort` with a range of either a `std::unordered_map` or a `std::unordered_set` will raise a compiler error.

### Questions:

1. Why STL's unordered containers cannot be sorted by `std::sort`?
2. Is there a legitimate and efficient way to sort either a `std::unordered_map` or a `std::unordered_set`?

Comment: If it doesn't make sense to add two togeather, do not store things as integers.  Adding two SSIDs togeather makes no sense, store them as strings or something.

Comment: It only makes sense to use mutating algorithms like that on sequential containers, of which `unordered_*` are not.

Comment: 1) `sort` has no clue what container the iterators are from, the error is because `sort` requires `RandomAccessIterator`s while `(unordered_)map|set` iterators are `BiDirectionalIterator`s. 2) There's a reason those containers are named **unordered** `_map|set`. If you want ordering use a `map|set`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`unordered` containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/hash_function/) store internally **hashed data** and thus it's not possible to order them after the hash has been generated.

In order to sort the data you can use an additional non-hashed container (e.g. map or set) and either use them along with the unordered version (so you can use the normal one to sort the data and the unordered one to have fast per-item access) or you can do something like

```
std::map<int, int> ordered(unordered.begin(), unordered.end());
for(auto it = ordered.begin(); it != ordered.end(); ++it)
     std::cout << it->second;
```

I recommend not to do the above often (unordered containers have slow sequential access)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6212709/1938163

Answer (score 5):

Sorting only makes sense for *sequence* containers, which are containers whose elements are determined by the order in which they were added to the container. The dynamic sequence containers in the standard library are vector, deque, list and forward_list.

Maps and sets, on the other hand, are *associative* containers, in which elements are identified by their *value*. Thus it makes no sense to ask for an "ordering", since the container elements aren't arranged in any kind of sequence. (It's true that an ordered map can be iterated in a comparison order on the key, but that order *emerges* from the container; it is not provided by the user.)

Answer (score 2):

> 1.Why STL's unordered containers cannot be sorted by `std::sort`?

Because unordered containers are *already* "sorted", albeit not directly by their keys, but by (typically) [`hash_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/hash_function)`(key) %` [`bucket_count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket_count)`()` (also accessible as [`bucket`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket)`(key)`).  This "sort" order isn't cosmetic - it's the whole basis on which hash tables are able to find elements quickly.  If `std::sort` were allowed to re-order the elements by key instead, then the container would no longer be able to function as a hash table: elements couldn't be reliably found or erased, insertions might put duplicates in the container etc..

> 2.Is there a legitimate and efficient way to sort either a `std::unordered_map` or a `std::unordered_set`?

In the general case, only by first copying the elements to a sortable or sorted container such as `std::vector` or `std::set` (the former will usually be faster, but benchmark both if you really care):

```
std::unordered_set<T> my_set = ...;
std::vector<T> my_vec{my_set.begin(), my_set.end(), my_set.size()};
std::sort(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end());
```

In your case with `std::unordered_map<int, std::string> DB;`, I'd suggest copying only the `int` keys to a `vector` for sorting, then during iteration look up each key in the `unordered_map`: that will avoid a lot of `string` copying.

(It is sometimes possible to orchestrate an unordered container with ordering by key (e.g. hash function returns key, container presized so max bucket index >= max key value) but anyone considering such abuse would be better off using a `vector`.)

Comment: This should be the answer, as it contains more complete information.