# how to output elements in unordered_map with keys in ascending order?

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I stored some intermediate results in unordered_map. Now when trying to output it, it shows that the keys are in descending order. Is there a way to display it in the other order? How?

Comment: What is "draft data"?

Comment: I meant some data for intermediate results. :)

Comment: I do think that this question is meaningful. Sometimes you want to use unordered_map for efficiency, but need it ordered to print it for debug purposes or for regression.

Comment: @101010's answer is the correct method for printing an unordered_map in order and you should check it as the right answer. This is often done for diagnostic purposes.

Answer (score 6):

You could copy your elements in a `std::vector` then use `std::sort` to sort this vector according to your preference ascending/descending and then output it:

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> um {{2, 3}, {6, 7}, {0, 5}};
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> sorted_elements(um.begin(), um.end());
std::sort(sorted_elements.begin(), sorted_elements.end());
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc71f4b943e38db5)

As for why you can't sort unordered STL containter take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212356/why-stl-unordered-map-and-unordered-set-cannot-be-sorted-by-stl-algorithms)

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer to keep intermediate data in sorted order, use `std::map<key,value>` instead `std::unordered_map`. It will sort on key by default using `std::less<>` so you will get result in ascending order.

`std::unordered_map` is an implementation of hash table data structure, so it will arrange the elements internally according to the hash value using by `std::unordered_map`.  But in case `std::map` it is usually a red black binary tree implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

**An unordered map is just that: unordered.**

[You cannot make any assumptions about iteration order whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3176643/560648).

This is the trade-off for the increased efficiency of some operations over an unordered map as compared to a normal map. If you want ordering, you'll have to sacrifice those increases.

Comment: Yes you can. Copy all the elements to another container that can be sorted as @101010 did.

Comment: @wcochran While true, I consider that "cheating", i.e. reframing the problem. It's like saying you can take a car up to 10,000mph by putting it on a spaceship. Can you take a car up to 10,000mph? Still no ;) Note that I _did_ say you can get ordering by sacrificing efficiency increases: copying the entire dataset to some other container is surely an example of that.