# Why am I not able to use the unordered_map in lamda function ? What is the data type of arguements being passed there?

Tags: c++, hashmap

Here is my code which sorts the string on the basis of frequency of chars.

```cpp
string frequencySort(string s) {
        unordered_map<char,int> umap;
        
        for (int i=0 ; i<s.size() ; i++) 
            umap[s[i]]++ ;
        
        sort (s.begin() , s.end() , [umap] (char a , char b) {
            if (umap[a] == umap[b]) return a>b ;
            return umap[a]>umap[b] ;
        }) ;
        
        return s ;
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Line 11: Char 21: error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const unordered_map<char, int>'
            if (umap[c] == umap[d]) return a>b ;
                ~~~~^~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/unordered_map.h:984:7: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const unordered_map<char, int>', but method is not marked const
      operator[](const key_type& __k)
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/unordered_map.h:988:7: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const unordered_map<char, int>', but method is not marked const
      operator[](key_type&& __k)
      ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda's function call operator `()` is by default set to const so you must either pass the map by reference (`&umap` or `&`), or use the `mutable` keyword to make the operator `()` non-const and pass by value (`[umap]() mutable{}` or `[=]() mutable{}`):

Passing the map by reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

std::string frequencySort(std::string s) {
    std::unordered_map<char,int> umap;

    for (int i=0 ; i<s.size() ; i++) 
        umap[s[i]]++ ;

    std::sort (s.begin() , s.end() , [&] (char a, char b) { // &umap
        if (umap[a] == umap[b]) return a>b ;
        return umap[a]>umap[b] ;
    }) ;

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "lollypop";
    std::cout << frequencySort(s);  // prints lllppooy
   return 0;
}
```

By value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

std::string frequencySort(std::string s) {
    std::unordered_map<char,int> umap;

    for (int i=0 ; i<s.size() ; i++) 
        umap[s[i]]++ ;

    std::sort (s.begin() , s.end() , [=] (char a, char b) mutable {  // or [umap]
        if (umap[a] == umap[b]) return a>b ;
        return umap[a]>umap[b] ;
    }) ;

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "lollypop";
    std::cout << frequencySort(s);  // prints lllppooy
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I wasn't aware of the concept of mutables but did some research and understood .

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda is capturing the `unordered_map` *by value*, so a copy is made. Since the lambda is not marked as `mutable`, that copy will be `const`. And `operator[]` is not implemented for `const unordered_map`, since it needs to be able to modify the `unordered_map` to insert a new element if the requested key is not found. Hence the error:

> no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const unordered_map<char, int>'

You would need to capture the `unordered_map` *by reference* instead:

```cpp
sort (s.begin(), s.end(),
    [&umap] (char a, char b) {
        if (umap[a] == umap[b]) return a > b;
        return umap[a] > umap[b];
    }
);
```

However, you will then run into a new problem.  The `value_type` of your `unordered_map` is not `char`, it is `std::pair<const char, int>`, so that is the type you would need to use for your lambda parameters, in which case there would be no need to capture the `unordered_map` at all:

```cpp
sort (s.begin(), s.end(),
    [] (const std::pair<const char, int> &a, const std::pair<const char, int> &b) {
        if (a.second == b.second) return a.first > b.first;
        return a.second > b.second;
    }
);
```

But that will not work either. This whole issue is moot, because [you simply can't sort an `unordered_map` to begin with](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24212356/65863). It orders its elements based on key hashes, and you can't change that order using `std::sort()`.

See [sort an unordered_map using sort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323135/) and [Sorting std::unordered_map by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212619/) for alternatives.